# SQL server - Group by and replace

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table

```
+--------+-----+
| Gender | AGE |
+--------+-----+
| M      |  10 |
| F      |  29 |
| M      |  30 |
| F      |  40 |
| F      |   5 |
+--------+-----+
```

and i want to have an output where it shows the oldest per gender and also add a column that indicate them as the oldest. what query im going to use ?

sample output:

```
+--------+-----+--------+
| Gender | Age |  Tag   |
+--------+-----+--------+
| M      |  30 | Oldest |
| F      |  40 | oldest |
+--------+-----+--------+
```

thanks for the help.

Comment: It's a simple `group by` query. Have you tried anything?

Comment: yep i tried anything but i still dont know on how to add "oldest" to the rows and determine them as the oldest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a simple `Group by`

```
DECLARE @SampleData AS TABLE
(
    Gender varchar(1),
    Age int
)

INSERT INTO @SampleData
(
    Gender,
    Age
)
VALUES
( 'M', 10),
( 'F', 29),
( 'M', 30),
( 'F', 40),
( 'F', 5 )

SELECT  sd.Gender, 
        max(sd.Age) AS Age,
        'Oldest' AS [Tag]
FROM @SampleData sd
GROUP BY sd.Gender
```

Returns

```
Gender  Age Tag
-----------------
F       40  Oldest
M       30  Oldest
```